# C# WinForms flicker by scrolling - Janus Controls

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar, janus

i got a little problem with a Control containig the Janus Controls ExplorerBar. The Size oft this ExplorerBar-Instance is much bigger than the max. Size of the Control, so a Scrollbar appears automatically.

Normal Scrolling in this Control (by Scrollwheel or by the Buttons of the Scrollbar) is no big deal and happens very smooth. But if I scroll by dragging the Scrollbar with the Mouse up or down, the Controls appear flickering while the scrolling is in progress. After releasing the Scrollbar, they paint instantly.

So my idea was to hook into the Scroll-Event of the ExplorerBar to make the scrolling smooth by myself (by deriving a Class     `MyExplorerBar` from the `Janus.Windows.ExplorerBar.ExplorerBar`). But there's no Scroll-Event. I also tried if theres a Method like `OnScroll` which I can override. But there is none.

So I thought asking a question here is good idea, because I allways got good Answers here. Do you know how to solve this Problem? Has anyone had the same or a similar Problem?

Comment: I've done this, but they also don't know how to solve this, so I hoped, someone here had a workaround for this problem :)